# Does anyone actually wear eyeglasses in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

**Does anyone in The Galaxy Far Far Away wear eyeglasses?** (specifically to correct for bad vision, NOT sunglasses or some special optics designed to enhance you natural senses ala whatever optics Vader's suit or Mandalorian armor provided).

(this arose out of random comment in Chat)

The question is mostly for G-canon, though I'll accept answers from T-/C- canons

Comment: R2-D2 wears beer goggles on Jaba's Sail Barge.

Comment: The Death Star has focus! =)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In addition to an abundance of Legends examples, spectacles have made the jump to new Disney canon:

- Nuvo Vindi, the mad Faust scientist from "Blue Shadow Virus" and "Mystery of a Thousand Moons", episodes of *The Clone Wars*

  [image]

  Although he doesn't wear them all the time (he appears to only use them when looking at something close-up), he does occasionally pull out a pair of [pince-nez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pince-nez) glasses.
- Gorga the Hutt, a member of the Hutt Council, wore a monocle

  [image]
- Though unclear whether or not they were corrective (rather than for safety or magnification), the Parwan Doctor Gubacher wore some manner of lenses in "Secret Weapons", an episode of *The Clone Wars* and his only appearance:

  [image]

Comment: A monocle can lend an air of class and gentle dignity that a giant murderous space slug might find lacking

Comment: Great. I didn't think we could get canon examples more distressing that Ewoks film. I shoudla known.

Answer (score 25):

[Noa Briqualon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Noa_Briqualon) from [Ewoks: The Battle For Endor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ewoks:_The_Battle_for_Endor).

[image: Noa Briqualon]

and [Saun Dann](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Saun_Dann) from [the Holiday Special](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars_Holiday_Special)

[image: Saun Dann]

In lower canons, the Wookieepedia entry for [spectacles](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Spectacles) lists a few others, noting that

> Spectacles were very rare, as advanced surgery and cybernetic implants were more efficient in many ways.

Comment: OK, can I please request that these two "sources" be striken out of canon and mind-bleached out of my head now? :)

Comment: I felt dirty just posting them.

Comment: @dvk - Is there a "Life Day" equivalent of 'The Grinch'?

Comment: @DVK Was mind-bleaching a common practice in the galaxy far, far away? :)

Answer (score 9):

We also have:

[Lonn Idd](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lonn_Idd) in *Star Wars Droids 2: The Ultimate Weapon*

[image: Lonn Idd wearing glasses]

and C-3PO (as a disguise):

[image: C-3PO disguises himself with glasses (an excellent disguise - you wouldn't know it was him!)]

Comment: Ah yes, the Clark Kent method of disguise.

Comment: Who's the droid in the bottom picture?

Comment: @Richard Wookieepedia reckons its 3PO, but I think it's General Grievous 

Answer (score 7):

[Noa Briqualon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Noa_Briqualon) from [*Ewoks: The Battle for Endor*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ewoks:_The_Battle_for_Endor) wears glasses :

[image: Noa Briqualon]

Answer (score 5):

## Doctor Pershing

[Doctor Pershing](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pershing) ([*The Mandalorian*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mandalorian), episodes 1x01 and 1x03) wears tinted eyeglasses:

[image: Doctor Pershing]

The doctor's reason for wearing these glasses is not yet apparent as of episode 1x03.  The glasses do not cover his eyes as laboratory safety goggles would, and they have not been shown to display electronic images.  Given that the lenses are not particularly dark and that he wears them indoors in very dimly lit rooms, it's reasonable to suppose that they are not primarily for protection against bright light.

Answer (score 2):

Also the [Kel Dor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kel_Dor#Biology_and_appearance):

> They also **wore goggles** to protect their eye fluids from evaporating.

[image]